# Parallels Desktop и HDD Windows 7

Tags: mac, образ

Есть HDD с установленной системой `Windows 7`.

Компьютер (ноутбук), в котором был установлен HDD физически сломан.

Каким образом можно сделать из диска образ, для запуска его в Parallels Desktop для Mac? Возможно ли такое в принципе?

Comment: В принципе да, если есть компьютер в котором можно этот диск завести. Про маки не скажу но на винде можно сделать vhd образ утилитой типа Disk2vhd , и этот образ импортировать в Parallels

Comment: @vnn198 то есть можно будет загрузиться с этого vhd образа в Parallels?